# Cumulative probability funciton of two independent variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have the following problem:

$Z = 3 * RND_1 - 5* RND_2 $, where $RND_1 $ and $RND_2$ are two independent uniformly distributed random variables they take values from (0,1) and we compose an equation of them this gives us Z

What is the $F(Z)$ - cumulative distribution function (CDF)?

I understand for solving this kind of problems i need to draw lines and then calculate the area where the inequality holds. When my teacher was explaining he confused himself and couldn't make the problem clear

[image]

For simplier notation let say $RND_1 = x ,$ $RND_2 = Y$

$Z = 3X - 5Y$

so $F(z) = p(Z < z) = p(3X - 5Y < z)$ ==

$3X - 5Y < z$ can be written as $\frac{3X}{5}-\frac{z}{5} < 5$

== $p(\frac{3X}{5}-\frac{z}{5} < Y$)

As i am writting this question i am starting to understand better the problem.
I need to determine where is the inequality holds and then subtract this area from the whole square's.

Can someone make the whole thing clear?

off topic:Please if you have any probability exercise book recommendation just let me know the name of the book.

Answer (score 1):

$Z = 3 X - 5Y$  so $P(Z < x) = P(3 X - 5 Y < x) = ?$ and 
Then you write this probability as an integral (try to justify for yourself why it holds)
$$\int_{xx=0}^1 \int_{yy=0}^1  \delta(3x - 5 y < x) dxx dyy$$ where $\delta(3x - 5 y < x)$ is equal to 0 is the inequality is not respected.
And then you can see that this integral is only making an integration on a part of a square.